# got an error when making an patch request

Tags: angularjs

when am requesting the `$http.patch` I got and error

> $http.patch is not a function

so how can I handle this error

```
$http.patch("http://94.237.83.114:3000/WF_CreateAccount", JSON.stringify({
    UserAuthName: $scope.UserAuthName,
    UserPassword: $scope.UserPassword
  }))
  .then((MediationResponse) => {
      console.log(MediationResponse.data);
      if (MediationResponse.data === "OK") {
        $state.go('app.dashboard-variant-1');
      } else {
        $scope.warning = "invalid Credentials";
        console.log($scope.warning);
```

Comment: there is no `patch` method in older versions of AngularJS. What version are you using? You need to update it to a more recent one (_1.7_). Or try a manual request: `$http({ method: 'PATCH', url: ..., data: JSON.stringify(...));`

Comment: my angular version is 1.7.2